# Using Lennard-Jones potential to generate $n$ oxygen atom coordinates that are evenly distributed on a sphere

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, coordinate-systems, gradient-descent

I am a student majoring in Chemistry. In my daily life, I often write input files of computational chemistry software. Most of the input files contain the **coordinates block** as shown below. It is quite easy to write the coordinates manually if the total number of atoms is not big. However, if the molecule has $1000$ or even $10000$ atoms, inputting their coordinates is not a trivial job, and that is why I am here.

```
Elements      x             y           z
O           1.084802    -0.240802   2.133771
H           -0.774428   0.497993    1.88079
O           2.419005    0.899744    0.191657
C           0.739285    0.563107    -1.493075
```

Recently, I want to write a script that can generate $n(n>100)$ oxygen atom coordinates automatically. These oxygen atoms are evenly distributed on a sphere and form a cavity, like [C60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene).
First, I thought of the [Lennard-Jones equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
V(r) = 4\epsilon\left[\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{12}
                      -\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{6}\right]
\end{equation}
Briefly, the **potential(V)** between two atoms is a function of the **distance(r)** between them. Here, the constants $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$ are related to the element type. According to the function diagram, when $r$ is not too large and not too small, the potential can be minimized. In other words, $V(r)$ has a global minimum. These must be very simple to understand for you guys. ; ) Because of the following two conditions, the equation can be simplified.

1. Because I want to restrain the distance between oxygen atoms to 3 angstrom, using the $\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{r_{min}}}=0$ and $r_{min}=3$, I can determine the $\sigma$ is about $2.673$.
2. Meanwhile, the *"amplitude"* of the equation is not important. That is I can set $4\epsilon = 1$.
   \begin{equation}\tag{2}
   V(r) = \left(\frac{2.673}{r}\right)^{12}
                         -\left(\frac{2.673}{r}\right)^{6}
   \end{equation}

After getting equation 2, I construct a cost function:
$$\tag{3}
\Theta = \sum_{\{ij\}\in set}V(r_{ij})
$$
$\{ij\}\in set$ means that $r_{ij}$ are all the possible connections between oxygen atoms. Therefore, an adjacency matrix whose diagonal is 0 and other elements are 1 can be constructed.
The workflow of my script is as follows. First, the coordinates of all oxygen atoms are randomly initialized in range $(0, 1)$. Second, the gradient descendent method was employed to minimize $\Theta$.
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x_i}} &= \left(x_j - x_i\right)\left(\frac{12\sigma^{12}}{r_{ij}^{14}} - \frac{6\sigma^{6}}{r_{ij}^{8}}\right) \\
\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{y_i}} &= \left(y_j - y_i\right)\left(\frac{12\sigma^{12}}{r_{ij}^{14}} - \frac{6\sigma^{6}}{r_{ij}^{8}}\right) \\
\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{z_i}} &= \left(z_j - z_i\right)\left(\frac{12\sigma^{12}}{r_{ij}^{14}} - \frac{6\sigma^{6}}{r_{ij}^{8}}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
During the minimization, I ran into two problems:

1. **Gradient explosion.** When $r$ is small, the gradient can be quite large, say $10^{12}$, and a reasonable $\alpha$ value is difficult to set.
2. **Gradient vanishing.** When $r$ is large, the gradient can be quite small, say $10^{-12}$, and a reasonable $\alpha$ value is difficult to set.

My question is :

1. **Is it possible to set an appropriate $\alpha$?**
2. **Is my cost function appropriate?**

Any insights would be appreciated. ; )

Comment: Something is not clear to me. You first said that you want the atoms to be on a sphere, but than you seem to ignore the contraint ?

Comment: Than, are your goals pedagogical or practical ? In the second case you could consider using https://lammps.sandia.gov/

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the comment! Actually, in the beginning, I also included a term in the cost function to restrain all the distanced to be the same. But  I found that I even cannot minimize the potential term (V) of the cost function.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. I will see that page.

Comment: Is some form of [spherical polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedron) not what you need ?  You'd be looking then at something like this question from Stackoverflow [Producing a sphere shaped hexagonal grid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777626/mathematically-producing-sphere-shaped-hexagonal-grid).

Comment: You are welcome. But personally, I would also follow the comment of StephenG and the stackoverflow link, instead of minimizing a loss function. My link was there just in case you wanted to push the "minimization" way.

Comment: @StephenG Thanks for your comment! In my opinion, the solution from Stackoverflow can generate a sphere grid. However, I do not need so many grid points.

Comment: @Thomas I have checked lammps, and feel overwhelmed now.  If you are familiar with this tool, could you please give me some input file examples to solve my problem? Can I restrain the distances between neighboring oxygen atoms when the code optimizes the conformation?